# Zend 2 Authentication Service Session for multiple sub domains

Tags: php, session, authentication, zend-framework2

I have 2 sub-domains and I am trying to authenticate an user via either sub-domains.

**Scenario:** 
Sub Domains: abc.example.com, xyz.example.com

User can login (login form) from either of the two domains.
Authentication is done from abc.example.com (ie. request is sent to abc.example.com only).

When user submits the form from xyz, a request is sent to abc and authentication is done. Upon successful login, the page is redirected back to xyz.

Now xyz creates a session on xyz and its all ok but the abc can't seems to find the already created session during authentication.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: not sure if possible. However I would do it in a way that when you redirect, you pass some sort of session id, which should be saved on a database, the server 1 should detect that parameter, look in the database and then create the session for server 1

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using 2 Authentication storage, one for each subdomain

Create 2 authentication storage and 1 authentication service in Module.config this way

```
public function getServiceConfig() {
    $subDomainAbc = "abc.example.com";
    $subDomainXyz = "xyz.example.com";
    $address = ''; // Get the correct address here

    $authenticationService = function($sm){
        // Declare and return the authentication service here
    };

    if($address === $subDomainAbc) {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'AuthenticationStorage' => function(){
                    return new AuthenticationStorageAbc("ABCAuthNamespace");
                },
                'AuthenticationService' => $authenticationService   
            )
        );
    } else {
          return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'AuthenticationStorage' => function(){
                    return new AuthenticationStorageXyz("XYZAuthNamespace");
                },
                'AuthenticationService' => $authenticationService   
            )
        );
    }
}
```

The authentication storage will now return the correct session service accordingly to the sub domain.

Hope it helps someone